# Returning values to tableView function

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to populate a label in a button in a custom table.  All is working, except I don't know how to send the calculated data from my `IBAction` function back to the `UITableView` function so it displays via the `return cell` statement.

**Please see code and the comments in the below code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak
    var lblHeader: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak
    var tableView: UITableView!

        var players: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.players.addObject("Hannah")
        self.players.addObject("Katie")
        self.players.addObject("Ashley")
        self.players.addObject("Kate")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
        return self.players.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!CustomCell


        cell.plrZeroes.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.plrZeroes.addTarget(self, action: "plrOnesAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func plrOnesAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        let pAvg = self.players.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as ? String

        ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** *
        HERE I WANT TO SEND “pAvg” BACK TO THE CALLER SO I CAN INCLUDE IT IN THE “return cell” LINE OF THE TABLEVIEW FUNCTION
        ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** *
    }
}
```

Comment: just fill the datasource again, and reload the tableview.

Comment: Thank you but this is all new to me. Can I get an example of what is meant by filling the data source and reloading the table. What cod e does that?

Comment: How do u intend to use pAvg?

Comment: just set the button title and reload row if needed, sender.setTitle(pAvg ........); tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexpath, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

Answer (score 2):

You can get cell using indexpath

let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection:0))